# Urllib not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib

I have Python 2.7.10 on Windows 7. Urllib works in IDLE shell no problem, however when I run the exact same code from lets say a file, or from `python urltest.py`

My code:

```
import urllib
page = urllib.urlopen("http://www.google.com")
contents = page.read()
print contents
```

I get the following error:

```
page = urllib.urlopen("http://www.google.com")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'
```

Keep in mind that this exact code works in IDLE shell (shell, not editor)

Comment: I use "webFile = urllib2.urlopen(rootUrl)"

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest your default Python is version 3, that no longer has urllib.urlopen (it uses urllib.request.urlopen).

IDLE is likely using 2.7.

Comment: But under v3 the "print contents" wouldn't work at all. Nevertheless the original code works just fine under v2.7, so something is mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

`#python3

import urllib.request
page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.google.com")`

the error is coming because when you run `python file_name.py` it's calling python3. type `python2 file_name.py`, it will work.

`# python2
import urllib
page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.google.com")`

Comment: Can you develop more your answer? (from review)